# How to properly check for a function using CMake

Tags: cmake

In converting from automake to cmake, I have to carry over some tests for function existence.  I didn't write the configure.ac script, but I do have to reproduce the functionality as closely as follows, so please don't berate me about these checks.  I have to make them.

So, I'm trying to use the CheckFunctionExists module to check for the existence of the time function (among others).  Here's the cmake code

```
include(CheckIncludeFiles)

CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS(time, HAVE_TIME_FUNCTION)

if(NOT HAVE_TIME_FUNCTION)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "ERROR: required time function not found")
endif(NOT HAVE_TIME_FUNCTION)
```

This fails every time, even though I know for a fact that I have the time funcion (duh).  I tried replacing time with printf and it still fails.  Is there some setup I have to do to make this check work correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should remove the `,`:

```
CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS(time HAVE_TIME_FUNCTION)
```

In CMake, separators are spaces or semi-colons, the comma is part of the variable.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that.  Thanks!  That fixed it

Answer (score 6):

Include the CMake standard module `CheckFunctionExists` and remove the comma in the `check_function_exists` invocation:

```
include(CheckFunctionExists)
check_function_exists(time HAVE_TIME_FUNCTION)
```

Comment: include(CheckFunctionExists) was actually in my original code, I just copy/pasted the wrong include for this post.  It was the comma, thanks